# Get time difference with extreme precision

Tags: c++, time

I whant to get the current time and use a function, and get calculate the time to make the function, with the most biggest time number possible... I have writed this code, but, always return 0 seconds :(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

void number(int numero, int *retNumber)
{
    int a = *retNumber;
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, numero
        neg eax // Apenas um ciclo da maquina, eba, mais rapido :)
        mov a, eax
    }
    *retNumber = a;
}

int main ()
{
    int numero = 10;
    int retorno = 0;
    monotonic_clock::time_point start = monotonic_clock::now();

    number(numero, &retorno);

    duration<double> sec = monotonic_clock::now() - start;
    cout << "f() took " << sec.count() << " seconds\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, if is possible to make this using code, I will do, but, if not is possible, what program I can use to make this ?

Comment: I see no `for` loop there. The compiler could just rearrange the instructions so nothing is measured, far as I can tell.

Comment: I doubt you can measure timing for such a small function by 1 call. Even if you would get some nanosecond value that hardly would be valuable as it cat easily fluctuate in order of magnitude. Put your function in a big enough loop and then measure.

Comment: what about "high_resolution_clock::now()" ?

Comment: OK, I have tried whit "high_resolution_clock::now()", but, the return is 0 ( whiout precision.. :( )

Comment: Did you try instantiating the `duration<double,ratio<1>>` class with a different ratio than the default (`ratio<1>`), eg.`micro`or `nano`? But be aware, that the timespan you're trying to measure is probably very small. May be a better idea is to put the `number()` function call in a loop (e.g. 10000 times) measure the time consumed for the whole loop and divide it by 10000 to get an average time span.

Comment: Have you actually analysed the code - it is entirely possible that the "number" function is completely removed, since you don't actually use "retorno". I can say for certainly that even using "rdtsc" (timestamp counter, which is a timer that runs at CPU clock speed or a constant speed around the top speed of the CPU), you will have more time spent on figuring out the current timestamp than it takes to execute those three instructions in the inline assembler. Use a loop and execute the code over a lot of numbers to see a reasonable result.

Comment: @Mats Petersson - good eye.